# Cloning and editing a site on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I just cloned an existing site on cpanel. It is a real estate website. I want to edit some text in the cloned site. How do I do this. Any help please. I'm on the cpanel but I have no idea where to go.

Comment: Most content on a WP site comes from the database, and then possibly a very customized theme.  Does the clone process also clone the DB? Even if so, it certainly doesn't edit your wp-config.php file to point to the new database, so the cloned site is most likely using the old site's database.

Comment: Yes it comes from the database. I copied the whole database. But the site says things like 75 north road on the old. I want to change it to 85 north road for the new

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a plugin to achieve your goal?  You could easily use a tool such as:
  https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/
  or
  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/

And deploy them on a different server or WP Installation.  WP-Clone in particular makes this process fairly simple and straight forward.  Not sure if I read your question right, but it seems to me that you want a simple, quick method of achieving this goal rather than manually exporting a database and/or Wordpress install.  Hope that helps.  Cheers.

Comment: Yes I know all those plugins but I decided not to use a plugin. The question I'm really asking is that after cloning to a new domain let's say the old domain was 85northpark.ca, and the new 95northpark.ca. Now I have this new domain 95northpark.ca with every single info and database from the old site. Now I want to change the texts on the new domain. I don't know if plugins help to do all of that .

Comment: Understandable.  I don't like to rely on plugins either.  You can access the PhpMyAdmin in your CPanel and execute some search and replace SQL to replace the affected areas, since it's not much.

Something like:
`update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'85northpark','95northpark');`

Where 85northpark is the text you want to replace, and 95northpark is the text you want to replace it with.